# how to sort numbers in html string in datatables jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

Im using DataTables jQuery plugin for my table. The problem is some column in my table contains text and number (like: `5 Pieces`, `2 Pieces`, `20 Pieces`). The DataTables plugin automatically sorts these rows like this:

- 2 Pieces
- 20 Pieces
- 5 Pieces

While I need it to be sorted like this:

- 2 Pieces
- 5 Pieces
- 20 Pieces

When I removed the 'Pieces' string, it worked well, but I need to use the word 'Pieces'. Can someone help? Thanks a lot..

---

Sorry for the same question, i tried [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deLhxk49/) and it works well, but somehow, i'm using a template for the HTML and CSS which includes this datatables plugin..

and the js code is written like this (this code format works well, but i cant use the formatted-num extended plugin with this format):

```
var initTable40 = function () {
    var table = $('#sample_40');

    var oTable = table.dataTable({

        "columnDefs": [{
            "orderable": true,
            "targets": [0]
        }],
    });
```

while in the jsfiddle (which is the one working) written like this:

```
$('#sample_40').dataTable( {
  columnDefs: [
    { type: 'formatted-num', targets: 0 }
  ]
} );
```

i tried to do this but it wont work as well:

```
var initTable40 = function () {
    var table = $('#sample_40');

    var oTable = table.dataTable({

        "columnDefs": [{
            "type": "formatted-num",
            "targets": [0]
        }],
    });
```

or tried to do this wont work as well too:

```
var initTable40 = function () {
    var table = $('#sample_40');

    var oTable = table.dataTable({

        "columnDefs": [{
            "orderable": true,
            "targets": [0]
        },{
            "type": "formatted-num",
            "targets": [0]
        }],
    });
```

thanks for help!

Comment: Please add the relevant example code

Comment: You'll need to implement your own custom sort logic to work on the integer portion of the string. Please add your HTML and datatables logic to the question.

Comment: Please see below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40188866/datatable-sorting-on-string-as-number. hope it helps

Comment: @ganesh Is correct.  This is a duplicate.  For your specific case, please see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/deLhxk49/