# Jquery Datatable sort not working with html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Sort won't work with html elements in table cell.

Tried adding the `aoColumnDefs` into it. Also specify column data for the column with `'sType': 'html'` and the sort does not seems to work.

Attached example code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zptdecaL/) (jsfiddle)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [datatable sorting on string as number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40188866/datatable-sorting-on-string-as-number)

Comment: @AnandhukrishnaVR can this supported on datatable version 1.9.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced this issue before on some project, use `mRender()` instead of `fnCreatedCell()`. The `render` function receives a `type` as a second argument from where you can detect if the rendering if for `'display'` or `'sort'` among other things. So, if type is `'display'` you can return the `HTML` and otherwise return the raw data.

```js
var data = [
  ["test", [20.2, "green"], "test"],
  ['test1', ['10.2', 'red'], "test"],
  ['test2', ['15.2', 'red'], "test"],
  ['test3', ['0', 'red'], "test"],
  ['test4', ['0.5', 'green'], "test"],
  ['test5', ['1.5', 'green'], "test"],
];  

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#data2').DataTable(
    {
      bSort: true,
      aaData: data,
      aaSorting: [[1, 'asc']],
      aoColumnDefs: [
        { 
          bSortable: true,
          sType: "numeric", 
          aTargets: [1],
          mRender: function(data, type)
          {
            if (type !== 'display')
              return data[0];

            return '<label style="color:' + data[1] + '">' + data[0] + '</label>';
          },
        }
      ]
    });    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src=https://cdn.datatables.net/1.9.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<table id="data2" class="">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>col1</th>
    <th>col2</th>
    <th>col3</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Solved my problem! Thank you for this! Jquery Datatable is problematic when it comes to HTML-comma or HTML-decimal number format. It really helps a lot.  @Shidersz

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with numbers followed by HTML, and no matter what options I chose the HTML change the numbers from being sorted numerically to alphabetically.

I finally came across the following (for my DataTables 1.11) which saved my bacon. I was able to output just the ID number that I wanted it to sort by into `data-order`, and that solved everything:

`<td data-order="{id}"><{id} <span>{DESC}</span></td>`